# How to evaluate the definite integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(M\pi\cos\theta)}{\sin^2(\pi\cos\theta)}\,d\theta?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given an integer parameter $M$, how to find the value of the definite integral

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(M\pi\cos\theta)}{\sin^2(\pi\cos\theta)}\,d\theta?$$

This problem is encountered in antenna theory.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know but may be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel can help.

Comment: I think that they are linear combination of Bessel J functions. For $M=4$, the result is $$4 \pi  (2+3 J_0(2 \pi )+2 J_0(4 \pi )+J_0(6 \pi ))$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a very clean looking solution, but here's my try.

We assume $M\ge 0$.

For brevity of writing, let $t(\theta)=\pi\cos\theta$. For ease, I will just call that $t$. We note that $$I_M=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(Mt)}{\sin^2t}\ \mathrm d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2\sin^2(Mt)}{2\sin^2t}\ \mathrm d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-\cos(2Mt)}{1-\cos(2t)}\ \mathrm d\theta$$

Now some trigonometry. We know that $$\cos((M+1)2t)+\cos((M-1)2t)=2\cos(2t)\cos(2Mt)$$

This gives us that $$1-\cos((M+1)2t)=2(1-\cos(2t))\cos(2Mt)+2(1-\cos(2Mt))-(1-\cos((M-1)2t))$$

Dividing by $1-\cos(2t)$ and integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$ gives us

$$I_{M+1}=2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos(2\pi M\cos\theta)\ \mathrm d\theta+2I_n-I_{n-1}$$

The integral is the Bessel function of the first kind, and gives $2\pi J_0(2\pi M)$. Plugging this in, we need to solve

$$I_{M+1}=4\pi J_0(2\pi M)+2I_M-I_{M-1}$$

with the boundary values $I_0=0,\ I_1=2\pi$.

Let $h_M=I_M-I_{M-1}$. Also let $4\pi J_0(2\pi M)=g_M$ Then, we have

$$h_{M+1}=g_M+h_M\Rightarrow h_{M+1}-h_M=g_M$$

This can be telescoped to get

$$h_{M+1}=h_1+\sum_{i=1}^Mg_i=2\pi+\sum_{i=1}^Mg_i$$

Plugging in the expression for $h_{M+1}$ and then telescoping again, we get

$$I_M=2\pi M+\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}\sum_{i=1}^jg_i$$

Thus $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(M\pi\cos\theta)}{\sin^2(\pi\cos\theta)}\ \mathrm d\theta=2M\pi+4\pi\sum_{j=1}^{M-1}\sum_{i=1}^jJ_0(2\pi i)$$

We can exchange the sums to get

\begin{align*}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^2(M\pi\cos\theta)}{\sin^2(\pi\cos\theta)}\ \mathrm d\theta&=2M\pi +\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}\sum_{j=i}^{M-1}J_0(2\pi i)\\&=2M\pi+\sum_{i=1}^{M-1}(M-i)J_0(2\pi i)\end{align*}

As a check, it matches with the answer for $M=4$ given by Claude Leibovici.

Comment: It's fairly clean actually. Get rid of the denominator, then linearize the trigs to make Bessel function appear. You get a simple recurrence, and it's done. You may also note that $\sin((M+1) x)/\sin(x)=U_{M}(\cos x)$ where $U_M$ are Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, but you still have to linearize $\cos^k x$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Ah, okay. I was a but unsatisfied because of the summation at the end. But maybe this is fine?

Answer (score 5):

We recognize something that looks like the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel). You can easily verify that
$$\sum_{|k|\leq M-1} \left ( M - |k|\right)e^{ikx}=\frac{\sin^2\left( \frac {Mx}2\right)}{\sin^2\left ( \frac x 2\right)}$$
Thus
$$\begin{split}
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2\left( M\pi  \cos \theta\right)}{\sin^2\left ( \pi \cos \theta\right)}d\theta &= \sum_{|k|\leq M-1}(M-|k|)\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik \cos\theta}d\theta\\
&=2\pi\sum_{|k|\leq M-1}(M-|k|)J_0(k)\\
&=2\pi \left(M +2 \sum_{k=1}^{M-1}(M-k) J_0(k)\right)
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Ah, forgot about Fejer, very nice. It gives a neat expansion of $\sin^2(nx)/\sin^2(x)$ as a linear combination of $\cos(kx)$. It's tempting, out of curiosity, to try to expand $\sin^3(nx)/\sin^3(x)$ to see if there is a nice formula. It turns out it is again a simple linear combination of $\cos(kx)$, though not as simple: not the same rule for coefficients of $\cos(kx)$ for $k<n-1$ and $k>n-1$.

Comment: Merci Jean-Claude. One way to look at the problem of expanding $\left(\frac{\sin \frac {Mx} 2}{\sin \frac x 2}\right)^p$ into Fourier series is to think of convolutions. To go from $p=1$ to $p=2$ is to multiply the Dirichlet kernel with itself once (to get Fejer). So you go from constant Fourier coefficients (rectangular window) to triangular ones (see absolute value in my answer above) by convolution. Then if you continue ($p=3$) you'll get coefficients as piecewise polynomials (in $k$)  of degree 2. And so on... Like some discrete spline windows.

Comment: It makes sense with the pattern on coefficients of $\cos(kx)$: constant for Dirichlet, arithmetic progression for Fejer, two different quadratic polynomials for $p=3$. but the generalization does not look obvious. It might be simpler with $e^{ikx}$? Anyway, I'll look at the convolution approach, it looks interesting. Thank you!